# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/<libname> is not on search path; what's the "right" way to fix that?

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, python3

On Ubuntu, I tend to run up against link errors for libraries installed under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/<libname>`, which doesn't seem to be searched by default.  In the latest example, I tried to use the Python binding of `fswatch`, which complains `undefined symbol: fsw_init_library` because the `fswatch` package installs the shared object under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfswatch` and Python (which seems to rely on gcc) doesn't search it.

I could hard-code a flag to add that directory to the search path like below, but this seems very brittle, non-portable, and just plain wrong.

```
if sys.platform == 'linux':
    os.setenv ('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfswatch')
```

This quickly becomes pretty complicated when I want to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for other purposes as well, or support non-x86_64 platforms as well, have more than one dependency suffering this problem, and so on.  Worse still, this incantation differs quite a bit depending on the toolchain: the code above is for Python; Makefile+gcc would need something else; cmake would probably want another, and so on.

Is there a better way of handling this, which avoids such platform-, package-, and tooling-specific cruft?  What's the "right" (intended) way of bringing libraries like this into scope, whose package doesn't care to put it on library search paths?  Is there a magic script that would set up environment variables the right way?  Is there a setting I'm missing to "enable" these kinds of libraries?  Something like pkg-config would be sufficient, but `fswatch` doesn't ship with a pkg-config `.pc` file.  I've taken up fswatch as an example here, but this is not the first time I got annoyed with this issue (though I can't recall specifics of past incidents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to this.

The first is runtime library resolution; this is what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` configures. The cleanest way to deal with this sort of situation is to create a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, pointing to the directory containing the library:

```
echo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfswatch | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/fswatch-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

The second is build-time resolution; there’s no single “best” solution for this, a `pkg-config` file is about as good as you’ll get but your builds will obviously need to know that they should refer to that.

Comment: `ldconfig` does provide an alternative, but the problem with that is it requires action on the part of the user (other than installing fswatch).  If I publish my code, I'd have to say in the README "on Ubuntu, you have to configure `ldconfig` to use this software", which is a non-starter.  The user will have to have root access, know how to configure ldconfig, know which directory fswatch installs libraries in, etc, etc.  That seems way too inconvenient to be the "right" way to use this library.

Comment: If you expect the user to install the `fswatch` package, they have to be root anyway, and you can provide the exact commands to run. `ldconfig` *is* the right way to deal with this, but it’s supposed to be set up by packages providing libraries, not packages consuming them, so I understand your frustration. I wanted to avoid making the answer specific to `fswatch`, but in this case you’re having to deal with the maintainer’s decision to [make the library private](https://bugs.debian.org/939382).

Comment: Ooooh, so this library is *supposed* to be unusable.  I missed that bug report.  That explains a lot of things, like why I have this kind of problem for only a few packages.  That's kinda sad, but this and your point about `ldconfig` clarifies the situation quite well for me.  Thanks.